# SHAP: additivity check failed in Tree Explainer: adding in check_additivity=False leads to error about keys not found in axis name?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shap

I have a data set like this, it's 343 columns of binary data, and it is sparsely encoded (i.e. there are many more 0s than 1s):

```
                      column1          ...          column343
0                        0  ...                          0
1                        0  ...                          0
2                        0  ...                          0
3                        0  ...                          0
4                        0  ...                          0
..                     ...  ...                        ...
214                      0  ...                          0
215                      0  ...                          0
216                      0  ...                          0
217                      0  ...                          0
218                      0  ...                          0

[219 rows x 343 columns]
(219, 343)
```

Could someone please explain to me how to fix the issue where this script:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold,KFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest 
#from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, RFECV 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, recall_score, accuracy_score, precision_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer 
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,recall_score,f1_score,roc_auc_score 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from numpy import mean 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import std 
from sklearn.utils import shuffle 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pickle
#import neptune.new as neptune
import pandas as pd
import shap


df = pd.read_csv('train.txt',sep='\t') #hard-coded
full_y_train = df['Event]
df = df.drop(['Event'],axis=1)
full_X_train = df


def run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid={}, output_plt_file = 'plt.png',model_name=RandomForestClassifier(),X_train=full_X_train,y_train=full_y_train,model_id='random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class', n_splits=5, output_file='random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class.txt'): 
      list_shap_values = list()
      list_test_sets = list()

      cv_outer = KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=1)
      for train_ix,test_ix in cv_outer.split(X_train):
              split_x_train, split_x_test = X_train.iloc[train_ix,:],X_train.iloc[test_ix,:]             
              split_y_train, split_y_test = y_train.iloc[train_ix],y_train.iloc[test_ix]  
              model = model_name
              cv_inner = KFold(n_splits=3,shuffle=True,random_state=1)
              search = GridSearchCV(model,param_grid=param_grid,scoring='roc_auc',cv=cv_inner,refit=True)
              result = search.fit(split_x_train,split_y_train)
              best_model = result.best_estimator_
              yhat = best_model.predict(split_x_test)

              explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(result.best_estimator_)
              shap_values = explainer.shap_values(split_x_test,check_additivity=False)
              list_shap_values.append(shap_values)
              list_test_sets.append(test_ix) 

      test_set = list_test_sets[0]
      shap_values = np.array(list_shap_values[0])

      for i in range(1,len(list_test_sets)):
          test_set = np.concatenate((test_set,list_test_sets[i]),axis=0)
          shap_values = np.concatenate((shap_values,np.array(list_shap_values[i])),axis=1)


      X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(full_X_train[test_set])
      cols = X_test_df.columns
      shap_sum = np.abs(shap_values[1,:,:]).mean(0)
      

      importance_df = pd.DataFrame({
           'column_name':cols,
           'shap_values':shap_sum
      }) 
           
      print(importance_df)

      return


param_grid = [{
               'min_samples_leaf':[1,3,5],
              }]

run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid=param_grid)
```

Generates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/data/ml_models_genotypic_only_fortest.py", line 103, in <module>
    run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid=param_grid)
  File "/home/data/ml_models_genotypic_only_fortest.py", line 80, in run_model_with_grid_search
    X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(full_X_train[test_set])
  File "/home/apps/easybuild/software/SciPy-bundle/2021.10-foss-2021b/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3464, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
  File "/home/apps/easybuild/software/SciPy-bundle/2021.10-foss-2021b/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1314, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
  File "/home/apps/easybuild/software/SciPy-bundle/2021.10-foss-2021b/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1374, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([  0,   4,  11,  16,  18,  19,  28,  29,  31,  33,\n            ...\n            156, 157, 175, 178, 192, 203, 204, 207, 211, 215],\n           dtype='int64', length=219)] are in the [columns]"
```

I do not get the error if I remove `check_additivity=False` from the script, however, if I remove the check_additivity parameter, I get the error:

```
shap.utils._exceptions.ExplainerError: Additivity check failed in TreeExplainer! Please ensure the data matrix you pass to the explainer is the same data shape that the model was trained on. If your data shape is correct, then please report this on GitHub.

Consider retrying with the feature perturbation=interventional option. This check failed because for one of the samples, the sum of the SHAP values is 0.908553, while the model output was 0.940000. If this difference is acceptable, you can set check_additivity=False to disable this check.
```

If I replace my data set with a fake data set:

```
full_X_train,full_y_train = make_classification(n_samples =500,n_features = 20, random_state=1, n_informative=10,n_redundant=10)
```

, I do not get the error.

So whether I leave check_additivity=False in or out of the script for my real data, leaves me with two different errors, and I'm not sure how to get around this?

Comment: This happens sometimes. Additivity check fails means base values plus shap values do not add up to predictions. You can either check this pointwise and decide this is acceptable to you. Or switch to another similar model

Comment: Thank you so much. Could I ask, when you say 'decide this is acceptable to you'. How would I do that - I would have thought that deciding that would involve setting the additivity check to False, but when I do that, that's what's giving me the error in the first place, so I'm not sure how to get around that error, if I decide it's acceptable?

Comment: Disable check. Debug error. See if the error acceptable to you. Try another model if not

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug your code as it's not reproducible but you may follow the following code snippet that "just runs":

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold,KFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
#from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, RFECV 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, recall_score, accuracy_score, precision_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer 
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,recall_score,f1_score,roc_auc_score 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from numpy import mean 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import std 
from sklearn.utils import shuffle 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pickle
#import neptune.new as neptune
import pandas as pd
import shap


full_X_train, full_y_train = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

def run_model_with_grid_search(
    param_grid={},
    output_plt_file="plt.png",
    model_name=RandomForestClassifier(),
    X_train=full_X_train,
    y_train=full_y_train,
    model_id="random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class",
    n_splits=5,
    output_file="random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class.txt",
):
    list_shap_values = list()
    list_test_sets = list()

    cv_outer = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
    for train_ix, test_ix in cv_outer.split(X_train):
        split_x_train, split_x_test = (
            X_train.iloc[train_ix, :],
            X_train.iloc[test_ix, :],
        )
        split_y_train, split_y_test = y_train[train_ix], y_train[test_ix]
        model = model_name
        cv_inner = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
        search = GridSearchCV(
            model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring="roc_auc", cv=cv_inner, refit=True
        )
        result = search.fit(split_x_train, split_y_train)
        best_model = result.best_estimator_
        yhat = best_model.predict(split_x_test)

        explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(result.best_estimator_)
        shap_values = explainer.shap_values(split_x_test, check_additivity=False)
        list_shap_values.append(shap_values)

    shap_values = np.vstack([sv[1] for sv in list_shap_values])
    sv = np.abs(shap_values.mean(0))
    cols = X_train.columns

    importance_df = pd.DataFrame({"column_name": cols, "shap_values": sv})

    return importance_df


param_grid = [{"min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 5],}]

importance_df = run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid=param_grid)

print(importance_df)
```

---

```
                column_name  shap_values
0               mean radius     0.000202
1              mean texture     0.000585
2            mean perimeter     0.000728
3                 mean area     0.000541
4           mean smoothness     0.000867
5          mean compactness     0.000098
6            mean concavity     0.000759
7       mean concave points     0.003325
8             mean symmetry     0.000033
9    mean fractal dimension     0.000349
...
```

Note, the above code runs on my machine with both `True` and `False` for `check_additivity` param